# can't access ubuntu's files from windows (samba)

Tags: networking, server, samba

I need to setup samba-share for 2 machines:

1. Ubuntu: x.x.27.48
2. Windows: x.x.16.218

These 2 PC is created on AWS within a same VPC and same subnet.
I successfully `telnet x.x.27.48 445` from Window.
I've set the Ubuntu box to accept connection on port 445 from `0.0.0.0/0`
I've install samba on my ubuntu followed [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-samba-server-share-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux), But I FAILED when trying to access files from Window through

1. `\\x.x.27.48\linuxconfig`
2. `\\x.x.27.48`
3. `\\x.x.27.48\public`
4. `\\my-ubuntu-name\public`
5. `\\my-ubuntu-name\linuxconfig`
6. `\\my-ubuntu-name`

I've checked and try solutions in `askubuntu` like `chcon` but nohelp. 
What's the problem? How could I share samba folder to Windows?

Here is the error image: 
[image: error when access from windows]

here is the console output when I run `sudo systemctl status smbd`

```bsh
$ sudo systemctl status smbd
● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-03-03 10:06:36 UTC; 10min ago
     Docs: man:smbd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
 Main PID: 16862 (smbd)
   Status: "smbd: ready to serve connections..."
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 1152)
   CGroup: /system.slice/smbd.service
           ├─16862 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
           ├─16881 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
           ├─16882 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
           └─16888 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group

Mar 03 10:09:25 ip-172-31-27-48 smbd[16930]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 03 10:09:25 ip-172-31-27-48 smbd[16931]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 03 10:09:25 ip-172-31-27-48 smbd[16932]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 03 10:09:25 ip-172-31-27-48 smbd[16933]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 03 10:09:25 ip-172-31-27-48 smbd[16934]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 03 10:09:25 ip-172-31-27-48 smbd[16935]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 03 10:11:21 ip-172-31-27-48 smbd[16947]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 03 10:11:25 ip-172-31-27-48 smbd[16948]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 03 10:13:33 ip-172-31-27-48 smbd[16953]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 03 10:14:35 ip-172-31-27-48 smbd[16954]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
```

If needed, this is console log for `smbclient -L localhost`

```bsh
$ smbclient -L localhost
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter WORKGROUP\ubuntu's password:

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
        homes           Disk      Home Directories
        truedata        Disk      test share folder qua samba de access tu windows
        public          Disk      public anonymous access
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (ip-172-31-27-48 server (Samba, Ubuntu))
        ubuntu          Disk      Home Directories
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.

        Server               Comment
        ---------            -------

        Workgroup            Master
        ---------            -------
        WORKGROUP            IP-172-31-27-48
```